# springdoc-openapi-ui swagger 3 change API description

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am new to String and Swagger 3.
How can I change the default API description i.e. `OpenAPI definition` in Swagger `springdoc-openapi-ui swagger 3`

[image]

Also version, developer information..

I am using

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.6"
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8"
```

In search, I see only they are showing default Swagger UI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply use following annotations :

**In application launcher class(Configuration class):**

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(info=@Info(title="Name of project"))
```

**In Controller imports should be as follows :**

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.*
```

**Calss level:**

```
@OpenAPIDefinition()
```

Or

```
@Tag(name = "", description = "")
public class ApiController {
```

**Method level :**

```
@PutMapping(value = "/test")
@Operation(summary = "info...")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successfully updated"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad request"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error")})
```

**And config class should be like this :**

```
@Configuration
public class ApiDocumentationConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiDocConfig() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("example API")
                        .description("example API for routing ")
                        .version("0.0.1")
                        .contact(new Contact()
                                .name("example")
                                .email("exaample@z.com")))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("Documentation")
                        .url("https:/wiki...."));
    }

    @Bean
    public MvcConfig mvcConfig() {
        return new MvcConfig();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Can you please tell me - How to hide request fiends on API wise?
I mean -
I have a common model User = 
{
  "userName": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "userToken": "string",
  "userType": "string"
}

Using same model(User.java), the Request body for "/sign-up" it should be like - 
{
  "userName": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "userToken": "string",
  "userType": "string"
}
But, for "/sign-in", Request body should be - 
{
  "userName": "string",
  "userToken": "string",
}

Comment: It's better create new question for this case.@CRSardar

Comment: Thanks, if possible please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138583/swagger-how-to-hide-request-fiends-on-api-wise-for-same-input-model

Comment: what about property file config ?

Answer (score 1):

For standard Version I used:

```
@Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        final String locUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
        final String devUrl = "https://.de";
        final String testUrl = "https://.de";
        final String preUrl = "https://.de";
        final String proUrl = "https://.grp";

        return new OpenAPI().addServersItem(new Server().url(locUrl)).addServersItem(new Server().url(
                devUrl)).addServersItem(new Server().url(testUrl)).addServersItem(new Server().url(preUrl))
            .addServersItem(new Server().url(proUrl)).info(
                new Info().version("v1").title("XApp application API")
                    .description("(NOTE: If having Swagger UI issues w/ Chrome then use Firefox instead.)")
            .contact(new Contact().name("Edi")));
    }
```

and to change based on grouping I did:

```
@Profile("!dev")
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupedPublicOpenApi10() {
        return GroupedOpenApi
            .builder()
            .addOpenApiCustomiser(openApi -> openApi.getInfo().setVersion("v1"))
            .group("API-v1")
            .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
            .displayName("API v1")
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: what about property file config ?