# Swagger - How to hide request fiends on API wise, for same input model?

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc

Using Swagger with SpringBoot

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.7"
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8"
```

I have tow REST end points, One is as follows -

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
public RESTResponse registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
....
}
```

For this, In Swagger UI, `Request body` should be like bellow -

```
{
  "userName": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "userToken": "string",
  "userType": "EMAIL"
}
```

Second is as follows -

```
@PostMapping("/sign-in")
public RESTResponse login(@RequestBody User user) {
..
}
```

For this, In Swagger UI, `Request body` should be like bellow -

```
{
  "userName": "string",
  "userToken": "string"
}
```

Where `RequestBody` i.e. `User` is same for both API, like bellow -

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User extends BaseResponse {

    @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userToken;
    private UserType userType;

}
```

How to make it?

Comment: I think it's not possible.

Comment: It's not possible to show things optionally. Further it makes no sense to use the same model for sign-up and login.